# Storing and loading lots of image frame numpy data into memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I want to store image frame data along with image frame timestamp extracted using OpenCV in an optimized way and then load it back to process it, here is the code:

```
import cv2
import pickle

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('/tmp/abc.mp4')
success, frame = video_capture.read()
fps = video_capture.get(5)
frame_number = 0

success = True
frames_arr = []

while success:
   timestamp = 1000 * float(frame_number) / fps

   '''
   frame is a numpy ndarray, Sample data given
   {'matrix': array([[[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]]]), 'timstamp': 123}
   '''

   frame_dict = {
       'timestamp': timestamp,
       'frame_matrix': frame
   }


   # Appending to frame array  
   # Conveting each dictionary to string and encoding it
   frames_arr.append(str(frame_dict).encode('utf-8'))

   success, frame = video_capture.read()
   frame_number += 1

# Storing all frames data into one pickle file
with open('/tmp/frame_data.pkl', 'wb') as bf:
    pickle.dump(frames_arr, bf)
```

If I directly save the dictionary it takes time and lot of space(2.2 Gb for 1700 frames - 1min video file), so I thought of storing it as a string (1.5mb) and again convert back to dictionary.

I am able to load the `.pkl` file and access the data but unable to convert it back to dictionary, here is the code to load and access the data

```
with open('/tmp/frames_data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)

for i, single in enumerate(data):
    print(single.decode('utf-8'), type(single.decode('utf-8')))
```

I get `type(single.decode('utf-8'))` as `<class 'str'>` so I tried `ast.literal_eval` but it throws

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7fa53e2c15c0>
```

If this is not the way, what are the other work-around, I have 4Gb of RAM and for 3-4 min duration video it hangs while saving if I do not convert to string and try to save direct dictionary.

Please help.

Comment: There's no guaruntee the pickled representation will not contain newlines.  Have you tried `numpy.save`?

Comment: Why not encode the timestamp in the image file name. What is the incentive of making it complex ?

Comment: @ZdaR you mean using `cv2.imwrite()` with the timestamp and again retrieve it back from filename?

Comment: @user2699 I did try `numpy.save`, It throws the same error.